# Does standard library support generating unique IDs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Assuming I have the following sequences:

```
A-B-C-D
A-C-C-E
B-B-B-D
A-A-E-D
...
```

I need to assign unique numerical IDs to every element, e.g. A=0, B=1 and so on and work with those IDs. At the moment I generate ID with the following function:

```
    id = -1
    ids = dict()

    def getid():
        global id
        id += 1
        return id

    def genid(s):
        global id
        if not s in ids:
            ids[s] = getid()

        return ids[s]
```

I'm beginner, so it may not be the perfect solution, but it works. However, I worry that it will be very slow/inefficient for *large* number of.sequences and elements (imagine instead of `A`, `B` etc. it has combination of letters `ABCD`, `XYZ` and so on). I believe `Python` has mechanisms to achieve this in a more compact way. May be `collections` library has something that can achieve this in 1-2 lines?

Comment: I have read your question a few times and still cannot quite understand what your trying to do. Is this sequence a requirement you cannot change? how are these sequences defined and how are they used in your code?

Comment: You can use the count() function from the itertools module to get each id number. You would get each id like this: return next(my_counter) https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.count

Comment: Also you do not need to check if s is in ids, ids is a dict and all keys are unique by definition.

Comment: @user2379875 Wrong. If he doesn't ensure `s not in ids` then `ids[s]` will be updated with every new `getid()` return value.

Comment: "I worry that it will be very slow/inefficient for large number of.sequences and elements" - I think you're worrying about an issue that will never occur.  Dicts are designed for quick membership checking and lookup.  If you need efficiency that badly, you probably want to change languages.

Answer (score 1):

uuid will generate a unique random id which can be represented as an int, bytes, or hex.

Just `import uuid` and then use `uuid.uuid1().bytes` or `uuid.uuid1().int` or `uuid.uuid1().hex` to get your id.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid `global` altogether, and as suggested use [**`count`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count):

```
from itertools import count

id_counter = count()
ids = dict()

def getid():
    return next(id_counter)

def genid(s):
    if s not in ids:
        ids[s] = getid()
    return ids[s]
```

You could use some "python magic" to make it shorter:

```
from itertools import count

def genid(s, id_counter=count(), ids={}):
    if s not in ids:
        ids[s] = next(id_counter)
    return ids[s]
```